# MySQL subquery and joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to join another table from this following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users u,
  (SELECT submissions_comments.parent_id from submissions_comments where id = 96) x
WHERE u.id = x.parent_id\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
            id: 17
         email: bobcobb@gmail.com
          hash: $2a$10$m9egfe.NtKC4QbR869el9.t.w0E7jN2Omk6AXQCbF/ERyfseJVx6S
          salt: $2a$10$m9egfe.NtKC4QbR869el9.
      username: test
          name:
          role: normal
         about:
       created: 2014-01-17 00:53:52
    last_login: 2014-01-17 08:53:52
    created_ip: 1270
 last_login_ip: 1270
   remember_me: 1
         photo: 
     confirmed: 0
  confirm_code: 814eaadfb411fb1a982c4b4b79b91cc37860c672
public_profile: 1
     parent_id: 17
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basically I want to join the `user.id` above (which is 17 in this case) to another table. The query below gives me what I want to add to the above query:

```
SELECT email_reply_on_comment
  FROM email_settings
WHERE id = 17;

+------------------------+
| email_reply_on_comment |
+------------------------+
|                      0 |
+------------------------+
```

I'm trying variations of:

```
SELECT * FROM users u,
  (SELECT submissions_comments.parent_id from submissions_comments where id = 96) x,
  email_settings.reply_on_comment
WHERE u.id = x.parent_id
LEFT JOIN email_settings 
ON email_settings.user_id = x.parent_id;
```

But not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following JOIN:

```
SELECT u.*, es.email_reply_on_comment
FROM users u
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT submissions_comments.parent_id from submissions_comments where id = 96) x
ON u.id = x.parent_id
LEFT JOIN email_settings es
ON es.id = u.id;
```

**Reference**:

[MySQL LEFT JOIN on MySQLTutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)